# Нужна помощь с регулярным выражением php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужна помощь с регулярным выражением. Практикуюсь на замене кода в файлах с помощью регулярок. Есть код в файле:

```
$list = array();
$list[] = '<form method="POST" action="edit">
                <a href="title1">Title 1</a>    
                <input type="submit" name="red" value="Edit Page">
                <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="title1">
                <input type="hidden" name="prev" value="'.$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].'">
            </form>
            <form method="POST" action="">
                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_delete" value="title1">
                <input type="submit" name="red" value="Delete Page"><hr>
            </form>'; 
$list[] = '<form method="POST" action="edit">
                <a href="title2">Title 2</a>    
                <input type="submit" name="red" value="Edit Page">
                <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="title2">
                <input type="hidden" name="prev" value="'.$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].'">
                <hr>
            </form>
            <form method="POST" action="">
                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_delete" value="title2">
                <input type="submit" name="red" value="Delete Page"><hr>
            </form>';
```

Написал такую замену:

```
        $link = 'check.php';
        $file = file_get_contents($link);
        $file = preg_replace('~\$list\[\][^<]+\<.*title1[^;]+\;~s', '', $file);
        file_put_contents($link, $file);
```

В чем суть проблемы. Регулярное выражение удаляет код с title1, не затрагивая другой код. Однако если поставить уже title2, то будет удаляться и title1, и title2. Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить его, чтобы удалять только определенный кусок кода, т.е либо title1, либо title2.

Comment: Зачем вы в регулярное выражение экранируете название переменной, будто она является частью строки, вы понимаете что это бред? И вообще вы пытаетесь заменить в элементах массива, а не `preg_replace` заменяет вхождения в строке. Вы понимаете что это неправильный подход?

Comment: Если ваши строки являются частью массива, то следует проходить циклом по массиву и делать уже замену на элементах. К тому же у вас неправильно составлено регулярное выражение.

Comment: Объясните, с какой целью вы храните эти строки в массиве?

Comment: @Let'ssayPie в зависимости от индекса можно выводить либо первую формочку, либо вторую. Все очевидно-жеж. А - Архитектура!

Comment: Мне нужна помощь только с регулярным) можно что-нибудь сделать или нет? То, что оно может быть построено неправильно, я даже говорить ничего не буду, так как только сегодня впервые взялся за них. Собственно, потому что взялся, хочу разобраться с задачкой, которую сам себе поставил, пускай она и неправильная)

Comment: @Arandar тренеруйтесь на примерах по-проще, и всё получится. Если у вас ещё не было практики в регулярных выражениях, то тем более нужно двигаться от простого к сложному, а не наоборот _(как сейчас)_

Answer (score -1):

В общем, разобрался с этой проблемой. Может и не совсем правильно, зато работает отлично. Если кто знает вариант лучше, то пишите)

```
~\$list\[\][^<]+\<[^>]+\>[^<]+\<[^"]+\"title2\"[^;]+\;~
```